# How does one group files with complicated file names using a bash script?

Tags: bash, find

I'm stuck.

**Ultimate Goal** - Concatenate multiple MP4 files into single MP4 files using FFMPEG to reduce the file count and make it easier to manage in a video editor.

The files that I've collected from my security system have a unique naming convention.  In each file name, there are some markers that denote the different camera angles.  Here is an example of one of the files:

`7845582F4FA9_0_rotating_2022-06-01T17.13.47-07.00.mp4`

| Prefix | Suffix | Number | Type | Date | Hour | Minute | Second | TZ | Ext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7845582F | 4FA9 | _0_ | rotating | _2022-06-01 | T17 | 13 | 47 | -07.00 | .mp4 |

Is it possible to find all files for a specific date from a single folder and ensure that the list produced is grouped by date, suffix, number, and then sorted by time?

Better yet, a separate list for each grouping?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: timezone complicates things, otherwise it's quite easy

Comment: how many files? what counts as "a specific date" (considering timezones)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example Bash script to accomplish this:

```
#!/bin/bash

loop_over_suffixes() {
  for i in *$1*; do
    local suffix=($suffix ${i:7:4})
  done

  for j in ${suffix[@]}; do
    echo "Loop over suffix: ${suffix[j]}"
    ls *$j*$1*
    # Do logic here
  done
}

loop_over_suffixes '2022-06-01'
```

You would call the function with whatever date you wanted. If you wanted to dynamically pass it todays date you could run:

```
loop_over_suffixes $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Just put in your logic where the `# Do logic here` section is. The `ls` command should sort by number and time automatically.

Comment: "The `ls` command should sort [...]" - No, it will sort by prefix, then suffix, and only then by number.

Comment: But I assume they are sequential, and therefore time sorted.